# Android - setOnClickListener stop working after navigating

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

Been working on an app for a while and navigating works fine in all tabs except for the 5th one. After navigating to a new screen and then back, all buttons stop working until I switch tab and back again. Then they work once until I navigate back again. It works fine with the same code in other. Any clues why?

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_more, container, false)
    }

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    biometricViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,
        ViewModelFactory()
    ).get(BiometricViewModel::class.java)

    initViews()
    initSettingsEvents()
}

private fun initSettingsEvents() {
    ll_currency.setOnClickListener {
        navigateRightLeft(requireView(), R.id.fragment_currency_selection, null)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting `ll_currency`? Is it a `lateinit` or `lazy` reference to a view?

Comment: All layouts/fragments are added to my nav_graph. If I navigate to it from another fragment and back, it still works but from fragment_more it stops for some reason

Comment: You're setting a click listener on something called `ll_currency` - you'll need to show how you're defining and assigning that variable. Have you checked if the click listener is actually firing, e.g. with logging in the lambda? That way you'll know if it's the listener or the navigation that's failing

Comment: It's a LinearLayout in the XML layout. I have set a breakpoint in setOnClickListener which stops the first time but then it just doens't go into the setOnClickListener  anymore

Comment: Are you using synthetic view binding from the old Android Extensions? (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration) That's been deprecated for a long time, and it might be causing problems (since `initSettingsEvents` apparently isn't setting a listener on the correct view). You should probably post the entire Fragment's code (including imports and `initViews`) to be honest, it'll be easier for people to tell you exactly what's wrong with it

Comment: No bindings or anything like that. Just a Fragment and a XML layout.

It's a settings page so basically just toggles and some buttons that lead to another page

Here's the relevant parts of the fragment. Basically setOnClickListeners all the way down.

Here's the XML, nothing crazy going on here either
https://pastebin.com/ZddvwjjC
https://pastebin.com/C63w3tth

Comment: You're using synthetic bindings, they're in the imports. If you can't post the rest of the fragment code, then all I can suggest is that the click listener is only being assigned to the view in the first layout you inflate, and after the Fragment's views are destroyed and recreated, you're displaying and interacting with a *different* view that doesn't have the listener applied. Probably because the synthetics are caching the first view after the first lookup, so you keep setting the listener on that even though it's not on-screen anymore. This kind of thing is why the plugin is deprecated

Comment: So what's the modern way of doing it? view.findViewById?

Comment: The modern equivalent is View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) which basically operates the same way, except you access your view IDs on a `binding` object instead of them being magic variables you didn't declare (that's why I was asking what the `ll_currency` variable was and where you were defining and setting it). If you look at that guide, the bit on using it in Fragments shows you how to handle the view creation/destruction stuff by rebinding to the new views. `findViewById` is the old-school way and that's always fine, occasionally it's ideal!